# WHERE clause in query with 2 joins and a GROUPBY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm aiming to return customers whose `total balance` is greater than `4000.00`. My query:

```
SELECT c.cust_id AS 'customer ID',
       c.address AS 'address', 
       i.fname AS 'first name',
       i.lname AS 'last name',
       SUM(a.avail_balance) AS 'total balance'
  FROM customer c INNER JOIN individual i
  ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
  INNER JOIN account a
  ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id;
```

Which produces this result

```
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| address             | first name | last name | total balance |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 47 Mockingbird Ln   | James      | Hadley    |       4557.75 |
| 372 Clearwater Blvd | Susan      | Tingley   |       2458.02 |
| 18 Jessup Rd        | Frank      | Tucker    |       3270.25 |
| 12 Buchanan Ln      | John       | Hayward   |       6788.98 |
| 2341 Main St        | Charles    | Frasier   |       2237.97 |
| 12 Blaylock Ln      | John       | Spencer   |      10122.37 |
| 29 Admiral Ln       | Margaret   | Young     |       5000.00 |
| 472 Freedom Rd      | Louis      | Blake     |       3875.18 |
| 29 Maple St         | Richard    | Farley    |      10971.22 |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

But I can't work out the where the `WHERE 'total balance' > 4000.00` clause should go. Presumably it has to come after the `GROUP BY`, but this doesn't work any which way I write it.

Comment: after the `GROUP BY c.cust_id` add a `HAVING SUM(a.avail_balance) > 4000`

Comment: @Lamak, not sure what stopped you from posting that as answer instead a comment and keeping the question open in turn.

Comment: @Rahul I'm using the android app and it's quite the PITA to post code there. So I posted the comment since there will be no doubt a lot of people that will actually post the answer

Comment: @Lamak, Ahh!!! that make sense now.

Comment: @Lamak Your comment was so fast and perfect - just sorry I can't accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.cust_id AS 'customer ID',
       c.address AS 'address', 
       i.fname AS 'first name',
       i.lname AS 'last name',
       SUM(a.avail_balance) AS 'total balance'
  FROM customer c INNER JOIN individual i
  ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
  INNER JOIN account a
  ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id
HAVING SUM(a.avail_balance) > 4000;
```

Comment: It's better not to use single quotes (`'first name'`) and to use either backquotes (`\`first name\``) or even better doublequotes (`"first name"`) for quoting aliases. Single quotes should be used only for string (and date) literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.cust_id AS 'customer ID',
       c.address AS 'address', 
       i.fname AS 'first name',
       i.lname AS 'last name',
       SUM(a.avail_balance) AS 'total balance'
  FROM customer c INNER JOIN individual i
  ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
  INNER JOIN account a
  ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
GROUP BY c.cust_id
HAVING `total balance` > 4000;
```

you can use column alias in HAVING queries to avoid doing a second sum

From the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

> The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent
>   to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)
>
> A HAVING clause can refer to any column or alias named in a
>   select_expr in the SELECT list or in outer subqueries, and to
>   aggregate functions. However, the SQL standard requires that HAVING
>   must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in
>   aggregate functions. To accommodate both standard SQL and the
>   MySQL-specific behavior of being able to refer columns in the SELECT
>   list, MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit HAVING to refer to columns in the
>   SELECT list, columns in the GROUP BY clause, columns in outer
>   subqueries, and to aggregate functions.

Comment: @Rahul's answer was fractionally quicker but this answer is more elegant and the extra information very useful.

Comment: @Jonathan Just want to point out the trade-off of generality versus the removal of redundancy that should be considered on an individual case basis. The operands in the `HAVING` clause can be arbitrary expressions. Also, I think MySQL is somewhat unique in allowing you to use aliases here - to my knowledge at least SQL Server and Oracle do not.

Comment: @ryachza Points noted. With this in mind, and following some further testing last night, I decided to accept Rahul's answer. Hopefully more people using different SQL applications will benefit from an answer that's not specific to my aliases.